# What is the best way to eliminate repetitive code

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I am writing to ask how to get rid of repetitive code for a page I am building. I began learning html about a month ago. I know about other languages but have never used any except for C. My knowledge of C comes from two intro programming college classes I took roughly 10 years ago. I did about zero programming during that 10 year gap.

My page currently has a container, a row, and three cols. Each col contains a bootstrap card. I want to eventually have dozens or hundreds of rows of cards on multiple pages. If I try to add more rows of cards, I quickly get hundreds of lines of repeating code. I image this would present a huge problem if I want to make changes to the cards in the future.

As far as I can tell, the only unique components of each card are the href and img src links, card title, and card text.

I have been reading about how to eliminate the repeating code. I came across several articles and I found out that I cannot achieve this with html alone. The articles mentioned using other languages and methods that I am not familiar with like javascript, jquery, template engine, blockwrapper. I would imagine that there are several ways to get rid of the repetition. Something I had in mind was using an object or function to pass the unique information into the cards, but I have no idea how to do that.

I want to use a method that is straightforward, conventional, and would open introduce me to new skills/languages. I am also open to novel or unconventional approaches. I would really appreciate the help.

[Screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm06L.jpg)
.

The code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card text-center border-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEGFFyv0MH4&t=1070s">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/iEGFFyv0MH4/mqdefault_6s_480x270.webp?du=3000&sqp=CLj_hPcF&rs=AOn4CLDOvo2tUWkm3QGC8E1BjBEWRa55Hw" style="width:80px;height:80px;">
          </a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Video 1</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Nighttime Ramen  [jazzy beats / lofi hip hop mix]</p>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEGFFyv0MH4&t=1070s" class="btn btn-primary">View Video</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card text-center border-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/8Zuwg_1Uit0/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CKixhfcF&rs=AOn4CLD445U_D61yZfcEysryoe_REtuCog" style="width:80px;height:80px;">
          </a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Video 2</h5>
            <p class="card-text">National anthem of Vietnam shown on VTV1 each morning</p>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0" class="btn btn-primary">View Video</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card text-center border-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rTuPEdlhQs">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/_rTuPEdlhQs/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CI64hfcF&rs=AOn4CLBuV_ZCwrAUoIj_dfv3in_OlYytNQ" style="width:80px;height:80px;">
          </a>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Video 3</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Baby Boomers Speaking To Us From 1989</p>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rTuPEdlhQs" class="btn btn-primary">View Video</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With the case you're describing, I would really recommend having a database store the video urls. You can even create a simple admin page with just an input field and an add button to store future urls in your database - if you don't wanna do it through the database workbench manually. Anyways, the idea is that you fetch the urls from the database, loop a html markup structure with the url fetched from the database. Your markup will then be dynamically created depending on the amount of video urls in your database. I could give you a small example in PHP if you'd like.

Comment: I am very interested in your idea of fetching urls from a database and using loops for html markup structure. That small example you offered to give would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you found a solution you will be moving forward with?

Comment: Thanks for your help Martin. I would like to move forward with your solution. I was curious, is there an alternative to the database for storing the urls in this case? Would it be possible to use something like an array or txt file to store the appropriate values? Then just like in your example, fetch data from that array or file for the surrounding loop around the HTML structure?

Comment: Yes, you can store the values into an array. Even a file (let's say CSV file) and store that content into an array. You can make it multi-dimentional to represent the same amount of fields from the database example. You could also hardcode the array and simply add new elements as you go along. The approach will be the same, loop through the array and print `[i]` index to fetch the content.

Comment: See the edit of my answer. I provided a solution using a multi-dimensional array that you define yourself as opposed to storing the data into an actual database.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Martin. It's simple enough for me to understand and works exactly as I was hoping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, I would recommend that you have a database store the appropriate values, then fetch the data from the database and create a surrounding loop around the HTML structure for the videos.

In that way, you'll have content dynamically created depending on the amount of videos stored in your database.

First we need to build the database and have some sample data. MySQL Example:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Generation Time: Jun 11, 2020 at 02:07 AM
-- Server version: 10.4.10-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.3.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `videodb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `videos`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `videos`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `videos` (
  `video_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_url` varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail_url` varchar(2500) NOT NULL,
  `video_description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `videos`
--

INSERT INTO `videos` (`video_id`, `video_url`, `thumbnail_url`, `video_description`) VALUES
(1, 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEGFFyv0MH4&t=1070s', 'https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/iEGFFyv0MH4/mqdefault_6s_480x270.webp?du=3000&sqp=CLj_hPcF&rs=AOn4CLDOvo2tUWkm3QGC8E1BjBEWRa55Hw', 'description of video 1'),
(2, 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0', 'https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/8Zuwg_1Uit0/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CKixhfcF&rs=AOn4CLD445U_D61yZfcEysryoe_REtuCog', 'Description of video 2'),
(3, 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rTuPEdlhQs', 'https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/_rTuPEdlhQs/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CI64hfcF&rs=AOn4CLBuV_ZCwrAUoIj_dfv3in_OlYytNQ', 'Description of video 3');
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Copy pasting this into a MySQL workbench should create the database with all the same attributes that I have worked with in order to provide this example.

As for the website example, I'll be using PHP for my backend scripting language and make use of the mysqli object oriented syntax.

An important thing to mention if you go forward with this style of programming, is that if you'll ever deal with user inputs down the road, **REMEMBER TO MAKE USE OF PARAMETIZED, PREPARED STATEMENTS**. This is **VERY IMPORTANT**. Otherwise, you'll be opening yourself up to SQL Injections (SQLI Attacks).

Website Example:

```
<?php
// DB variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "videodb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if($conn->connect_error){
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Declare the query
$sql = "SELECT video_id, video_url, thumbnail_url, video_description FROM videos";

// Prepare
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// Execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// Get result of query
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// Close connection
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Index Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                // Check if any rows are returned
                if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // Loop through the result(s)
                    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="card text-center border-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                <a href="<?php echo $data['video_url']; ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $data['thumbnail_url']; ?>" style="width:250px;height:250px;" />
                                </a>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Video <?php echo $data['video_id']; ?></h5>
                                     <p class="card-text"><?php echo $data['video_description']; ?></p>
                                     <a href="<?php echo $data['video_url']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View Video</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                     }
                }
                // If no rows, no videos were found
                else
                {
                    ?><div class="col text-center"><h1>NO VIDEOS FOUND</h1></div><?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Like I also mentioned in my comment, you could even create a small admin page where you could have `<input type="text" />` elements for the video and thumbnail urls, a `<textarea>` element for the video description and a `<button>` element to add all the values to the database so you wouldn't have to necessarily do it through the database workbench.

**EDIT:**

You asked in a comment whether there are alternatives to the database approach in terms of storing your video data.

One thing you could do is make use of a multi-dimensional array and loop through that. It's basically what you're doing when you're fetching data from a database as well.

**Example:**

```
<?php
// multi-dimensional array
$videoArray = array(
                array(
                    "1", 
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEGFFyv0MH4&t=1070s",
                    "https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/iEGFFyv0MH4/mqdefault_6s_480x270.webp?du=3000&sqp=CLj_hPcF&rs=AOn4CLDOvo2tUWkm3QGC8E1BjBEWRa55Hw",
                    "Description of video 1"
                ),
                array(
                    "2", 
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0",
                    "https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/8Zuwg_1Uit0/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CKixhfcF&rs=AOn4CLD445U_D61yZfcEysryoe_REtuCog",
                    "Description of video 2"
                ),
                array(
                    "3", 
                    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEGFFyv0MH4&t=1070s",
                    "https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/_rTuPEdlhQs/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CI64hfcF&rs=AOn4CLBuV_ZCwrAUoIj_dfv3in_OlYytNQ",
                    "Description of video 3"
                )
            );

$video_id = 0; // id index
$video_url = 1; // video url index
$video_thumbnail = 2; // thumbnail url index
$video_description = 3; // description index

// check if any data
if(count($videoArray) > 0)
{
    // loop through array
    for($i = 0; $i < count($videoArray); $i++)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card text-center border-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <a href="<?php echo $videoArray[$i][$video_url]; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $videoArray[$i][$video_thumbnail]; ?>" style="width:250px;height:250px;" />
                </a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Video <?php echo $videoArray[$i][$video_id]; ?></h5>
                     <p class="card-text"><?php echo $videoArray[$i][$video_description]; ?></p>
                     <a href="<?php echo $videoArray[$i][$video_url]; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">View Video</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
// else if no data, no videos were found
else
{
     ?><div class="col text-center"><h1>NO VIDEOS FOUND</h1></div><?php
}
?>
```

You could also have a file that contains your video data. Let's say a `.CSV` file and then your can use a `delimiter` to separate your contents, store the data from that file into a multi-dimensional array and work with that in the same approach.

When you save a CSV file (at least from Excel), you can choose which kind of separation you want. `;` would be a great choice of `delimiter` in your case.

I am not going to go into detail about how to load in a CSV file and build an array upon its contents. You can research that on your own if its something you want to look into. I feel like that would be another question in its own, best asked separately from this one.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible. HTML is a markup language, and cannot be used for defining logic such as a method to generate content.

Comment: Well, there's always JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML is the final result that will be processed by the browsers, there's almost nothing you can do without using Javascript (or any JS frameworks like jQuery, Angular, React...)

The only thing you can do is reduce the footprint of your HTML, but this became impossible if you are using bootstrap (you are tied to it markup to allow using it style).

For example, your video block can be just this:

```css
.video-card-container {
  display: flex;
}

.video-card {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.video-card > div > h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.video-card > div > p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.video-card > div > a {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #6666FF;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-card-container">
    <div class="video-card">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/8Zuwg_1Uit0/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CKixhfcF&rs=AOn4CLD445U_D61yZfcEysryoe_REtuCog" style="width:80px;height:80px;">
      </a>
      <div>
        <h5>Video 2</h5>
        <p>National anthem of Vietnam shown on VTV1 each morning</p>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0">View Video</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-card">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/8Zuwg_1Uit0/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CKixhfcF&rs=AOn4CLD445U_D61yZfcEysryoe_REtuCog" style="width:80px;height:80px;">
      </a>
      <div>
        <h5>Video 2</h5>
        <p>National anthem of Vietnam shown on VTV1 each morning</p>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0">View Video</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video-card">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/8Zuwg_1Uit0/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CKixhfcF&rs=AOn4CLD445U_D61yZfcEysryoe_REtuCog" style="width:80px;height:80px;">
      </a>
      <div>
        <h5>Video 2</h5>
        <p>National anthem of Vietnam shown on VTV1 each morning</p>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zuwg_1Uit0">View Video</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And since the markup is always this for a `video-card`, the stylesheet (css) becomes very simple, and you don't need to put a lot of classes for everything.

The downside is that you will not be able to take advantage of bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for your example. You mentioned that there is almost no way to do this with html only. May I please ask you how to achieve this by using Javascript?

Comment: JavaScript will just reduce the manually created markup, but you will still end up with a lot of markup